# Go to New Page based on selected options

Tags: javascript

I have got a code that allows the user to choose options from select drop down list.
But because it uses option's "value" to generate the new list (more accurately to link the selection list together) which means I can't use it to pass on URL to my gotoNewPage function. Is there a way to get around it?

```
       <script> 
        function goToNewPage()
      {
        var url = document.getElementById('niv2').value;
        console.log(url);
        if(document.getElementById('niv2').value!='nothing'){
           window.open(url,'_blank');
        }
      }
      </script>

                             <form id="formname" name="State-Category-Organiser"> 
                                            <P style="font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-style: normal">State</p>
                                            <select data-child="niv1" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
                                                <option value="1-1">QLD</option>
                                                <option value="1-2">NSW</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div >
                                            <P style="font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-style: normal">Sports</p>
                                            <select id="niv1" data-child="niv2" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
                                                <option data-group="1-1" value="1-1-1">Brisbane</option>
                                                <option data-group="1-2" value="1-2-1">Sydney</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div >
                                            <P style="font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-style: normal">Organiser</p>
                                            <select id="niv2" data-child="niv3" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
                                                <option data-group="1-1-1" value="1-1-1-1">Tommy</option>
                                                <option data-group="1-1-1" value="1-1-1-1">Franks</option>
                                                <option data-group="1-1-1" value="1-1-1-1">Jacky</option>
                                                <option data-group="1-1-1" value="1-1-1-1">Simon</option>

                                        </div>
                                        <div >
                                        <input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" /> </form>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $("[data-child]").change(function() {
                                      const selectedGroup = $(this).val();
                                      var $childSelect = $("#" + $(this).attr("data-child"));
                                      value = $childSelect.find('option').hide()
                                      .filter(function (i, e) {
                                        return $(e).val().startsWith(selectedGroup)
                                      }).show().eq(0).val();
                                      $childSelect.val(value);
                                      $childSelect.trigger('change');
                                    });
                                    $("[data-child]").eq(0).trigger('change');
                            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use any other `data-attribute`. Just taking it won't be as accessible as `.value` but still possible.

```js
function goToNewPage() {
  var select = document.getElementById('niv2');
  var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex]
  var url = option.getAttribute("data-url")
  console.log(url);
}
```

```html
<select id="niv2" data-child="niv3" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
  <option data-url="http://example1.com" data-group="1-1-1" value="1-1-1-1">Tommy</option>
  <option data-url="http://example2.com" data-group="1-1-1" value="1-1-1-1">Franks</option>
  <option data-url="http://example3.com" data-group="1-1-1" value="1-1-1-1">Jacky</option>
  <option data-url="http://example4.com" data-group="1-1-1" value="1-1-1-1">Simon</option>
</select>


<input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />
```